# making a responsive image vertically centered inside div

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is bigger than its container div. When the browser/screen resizes, it should make the image bigger or smaller but always keeping the center of the image  centered inside the div. One example of this is the following website: http://www.qdoba.com/ . They have their images centered as you resize the screen making it very well responsive. What I have at the moment only makes it resize horizontally but not vertically. This is what I have so far:

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide{ 
    width:100%; 

} 
.slide img{ 
    width:100%; 
}
</style>

<div class="swiper-container">
   <div class="slide">
        <img src='http://www.envision-creative.com/wp-content/uploads/Tiagos01.jpg' />
        <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still having problems with this. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHzek/

Comment: as you can see in the fiddle, i want to keep the container at height:300 max. but when the page resizes i want the image to re-position itself to the middle. It looks nice when the image is in a small screen, but when it is on a bigger screen, I can only see the top of the image. I want to see the middle of the image when I am viewing the page on a large screen. Please let me know if you are able to understand me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got an answer to my question. Perhaps I was not explaining it correctly but what I initially needed was to make sure the center of my image was vertically centered inside a div. The answer could not be done with just HTML and CSS but javascript needed to be implemented. so here it is **[CHECK OUT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/McJeu/)**:

```
<style>
.swiper-container {
    width:100%;
}

.slide{ 
    width:100%; 
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.slide img{ 
    width:100%; 
}
</style>

<div class="swiper-container">
   <div class="slide">
        <img src='http://www.envision-creative.com/wp-content/uploads/Tiagos01.jpg' />
        <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var imageHeight, wrapperHeight, overlap, container = $('.slide');

    function centerImage(){
       imageHeight = container.find('img').height();
       wrapperHeight = container.height();
       overlap = (wrapperHeight - imageHeight)/2;
       container.find('img').css('margin-top', overlap);
    }

    $(window).bind("load resize", centerImage);

 });

<script>
```

Comment: I've posted a complete answer.. check it out.

Comment: oh i see, i tried the fiddle and it isnt working. I will try the code locally.

Comment: ok i tried it. Well, I see what you did, and its cool, but its not what I needed. The problem I had was that the image I have is bigger than my div. for example I need the div container to be a height of 200px. but the image height is 600px. I need the image centered inside this div regardless of it loosing top and bottom portions. just like the http://www.qdoba.com sample that I initially posted.

Comment: Ok, so its a different problem from what I initially thought.. but still.. very doable with CSS only :) I will post a new solution soon..

Comment: that'll be awesome. I appreciate your time and interest.

Comment: I posted a fiddle of my solution. Check it out to give you a better idea on how to do this with CSS only. Thanks

Comment: Ok. edited my old answer. I hope that i understood right this time. (this is only the idea, you'll need to apply it to your current HTML)

Comment: I've tried your fiddle.. did you wanted the 'slide 1' text to disappear when there isn't enough space for the image? or that is an unwanted behavior that you'll have to live with? (because it can be fixed..)

Comment: Nice, I see it. Although it is not doing it vertically. Were you able to see my fiddle? check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/McJeu/. Resize it sideways to see it in action

Comment: ah.. the 'slide1' was just a filler. you can ignore that

Comment: I saw your fiddle from your answer.. about the vertical, its because i simply fixed the container with a static height.. but it will behave the same as the horizontal with % height. check out the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/6sgy2/2/ (also updated in the answer)

Comment: See my post for a way to do this using just html/css supporting IE8+.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple. [Jump to the end of the answer for the updated Fiddle]

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">
    <span class="Centerer"></span><div class="Centered">
        <img src='http://imageshack.us/a/img19/3207/15p0213.jpg' />
        <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
.slide
{ 
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; /*not really needed*/
}
.Centerer
{
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Centered
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*you don't always want your centered stuff to be 100% width, so its in a different rule*/
.Content
{
    width: 100%;
}
.Content img
{
    max-width: 30%; /*so you can see the responsive alignment and size*/
}
```

If you don't set any height to the Slide, it will always have the exact height of its content, so it will look like there is no vertical alignment.

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/VbsKK/)

**EDIT**
I didn't understood you correctly.
Check out this [**New Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/6sgy2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="slide">
    <img src='images/test.jpg' />
    <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
</div>

<style>
.slide{ 
    width:100%; 
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 200px; /* you have to make height static */
 } 

.slide img{
   width:100%; 
} 
</style>
```

Comment: can please put it on jsbin and jsfiddle

Comment: its should working, and images will vertical middled if your code is right here?

Comment: this is still not working. I posted a fiddle above, and also edited to hopefully better explain myself. thanks

Comment: i understand what you are doing, and i appreciate the time and effort but it is not what I am looking for. Perhaps I am not explaining it correctly. ..hmm.. lets say my div's height is 200px. but lets say my image's height is 500px. How do I make sure that my image's center is always on the center of the div?

Comment: nope, if image's height is more that div height, you sholud write it clearly in above answer, so someelse may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to you, also for a responsive slider component that I was building.

My requirements:

- The slider container must have a 100% width against the viewport and it must have a fixed height.
- The images within the slider must stretch to the full width of the slider.
- The images must maintain their aspect ratio so they are not distorted.
- The images must always be vertically aligned to the middle of the slider container to create a "center crop" effect for any of the image which doesn't fit within the restricted height of the slider container.

I managed to achieve this without the use of any javascript based on principles from the following smashing magazine post: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/2

Here is a generic form of my html, without any noise, to illustrate how to solve this problem:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/animals/1" />
</div>
```

And here is the minimal css required:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can see a fiddle of this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kjfasbt/

It's a very basic implementation, focusing on the problem, but you could easily take this and drop it into a slider implementation and add fancy media queries for some extra effect.

You could of course modify the CSS to give the image other dimensions, pixel or percentage, it would still center. :)

Comment: I believe this has browser support of IE8+